# UIImage Caching

Tags: ios, caching, uiimage

Its is well documented that UIImage imageNamed caches the images. And the trend with the newer version of iOS is to use Asset Files to simplify all the @2x and @3x images for all devices.

But to avoid caching the images and to make best use of memory with images, so far I would use methods like imageWithData. But these methods don't work with Asset files that has been my understanding so far. Cause I could not find methods like pathForResource on the bundle working properly for Asset images. Is this a drawback on iOS or is there a nice workaround or is it just plain n00b ness on my behalf?

On one of my projects I have noticed a large memory consumption only because some image used on some startup screen or so still being cached courtesy imageNamed:

How can one work around this i.e continue using the simplicity and ease of Asset set Images and yet avoid caching using imageNamed:

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although `UIImage's` `imageNamed` caches the images, and some of the old forums continue to dole out that information. In earlier OS version, imageNamed had a memoryLeak, which has long been fixed.

When app receives memory warning, cache is cleared. So you can continue to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but my concern is that stage where the app hasn't received the memory warning, but has allocated lots of memory which is cached...which leads to sluggish performance as on table view or on animation effects. Essentially as I mentioned I wanted to avoid caching as much as possible  but for place like scroll view or table view cells using imageNamed: but at the same time avoid using caching by using pathForResource all the while using Asset Sets. Is this possible? Maybe my question can be rephrased as using pathForResource for Images in Assets

Comment: @0x6d6e 1. Keep in mind that if you app has taken up a lot of memory, things will not get sluggish. If there is performance effect on TableView or on animations, it could be indicative of computation intensive or some I/O related elsewhere. And if the memory you are taking up, reaches near critical levels, (where OS may think that animations may get sluggish), it will send memory warning, and if memory persists/exceeds, it will kill it. 2. Nevertheless, I will update my answer for pathForResource bit in a shortwhile.

Comment: Thank you Look forward to your reply. Right now my App is getting terminated with a clearing warning/Dialog on Xcode which states too much memory consumed and Instruments shows UIIMage is the main culprit.